# Spreading array to set a new state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6, setstate

I am working in React.JS and trying to set a new state by spreading array of objects and changing a value of one of them. I have an array of objects with key and another object as a value. Like this:

```
    [
        {"first": {
            "backlog":[...]
            }
        }, 
        {"second": {
            "backlog":[...]
            }
        },
        {"third": {
            "backlog":[...]
            }
        }
    ]
```

I also have variable `selected` with one of object's key as a value. So I want to spread my entire array as a new state, but with a slight change to a `backlog` of exact object. The key of it's object is saved in `selected` variable. The problem is, I can't reach it the object I need. I tried to do it like this, but I understand where I was wrong:

```
setProjects((prevProjects) => 
            ([...prevProjects, [selected]: {...prevProjects[selected], backlog: [...prevProjects[selected].backlog, NewObj ]}])
        )
```

Is it even possible to achieve? If yes, how?

Comment: That's a pretty suspicious data structure. Any chance you could change it to be easier to manipulate (such as a single object)? That's what I'd suggest. `{ first: [...], second: [...] }`

Comment: Mixed-key arrays of objects are hard to work with. Consider also `[{name: "first", backlog: [...]}, {name: "second", backlog: [...]}, ...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to find the index of the object with the key in the outer array, and then update that index while mapping over the state.

```
const index = projects.findIndex(obj => obj[selected]);
setProjects(
  projects.map((project, i) => (
    i === index
      ? { backlog: [...project.backlog, NewObj] }
      : project
  ))
);
```

But consider if you could use an easier data structure to make manipulations of it easier.

```
const [projects, setProjects] = useState({
  first: [...], // first backlog
  second: [...], // second backlog
  // etc
});
```

Then you can update with

```
setProjects({
  ...projects,
  [selected]: [...projects[selected], NewObj]
});
```

---

You don't need to use the callback form (`setProjects((prevProjects) =>`) unless you've previously updated the `projects` state synchronously *and* the component hasn't re-rendered yet. Sometimes it's necessary, but usually it isn't.

Comment: Thank you. This is a really great answer. Now I have more then one solution. I might change a data structure